# Best practices about creating methods with callbacks

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to write a method which do some asynchronous stuff (HTTP GET request) and call some methods provided as callbacks when it is finished.

What is the appropriate way to do such things in Objective-C? Should I provide one completion callback for both success and error handling or should I pass them as separate arguments?

Also, how should I name such method? What is the best practices here?

Comment: This is a good issue to talk about, but probably better on [programmers.se].

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a delegate and calling a completion method in the delegate when the async process is complete is one way.

In the past several years Apple, and the greater iOS/Mac community, has been shifting away from that design pattern. Instead, you are more likely to find a method that takes a completion block. That completion block might have a success parameter, a data parameter, and an error parameters.

Take a look at the `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method in the now-deprecated NSURLConnection class as an example, or the more recent `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` method in NSURLSession. Both take a completion handler that gets called when the async request has finished processing.

I have shifted my habits and am much more likely to use completion blocks rather than delegates and callbacks in new designs.

Comment: I don't think it's the case that anyone is shifting away from the protocol-delegate pattern.  It entirely depends on what sort of relationship the two objects have.  As always, use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Often you can use either approach. Before blocks existed, you (obviously) couldn't use them. Now, they are an option, and in cases where you could use either, blocks have some advantages. Sure, there are still cases where the delegate pattern is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preference. My preference is to have a single callback. On that, I will check for errors. If no errors exists, then I will assume that the response is a success and then start the relevant processing.

Comment: So there's no general practice for such cases?